# How to continue extruding Bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

While shaping a Bezier curve it allowed me to continue a smooth curve giving me 3 handle points at every vertex, however at the end, when I try to extrude it, it loses its curve and goes completely straight. What’s the fix?

Comment: Select the control point and V > Aligned?